# View page source in Chrome is extremely slow

Tags: google-chrome, performance

When making a page request to see the output of a large object, via a PHP's `var_dump` or `print_r`, a regular Chrome page will display the output quickly. To see a formatted output, I usually view the source.

This almost invariably locks up both the "view source" tab and the tab containing the original, unformatted output.

The same thing can be caused by going to the resources tab of the Element Inspector, and trying to view the document there.

Comment: Are you running any plugins? I had a code highlighter plugin active that caused these symptoms. Try disabling all plugins and trying again.

Comment: Having the same issue with Chrome Version 33.0.1726.0 dev. No plugins running, it started running slow after upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Disable ALL plugins and try again, see if that helps.  If nothing, then post results of behavior after disabling plugins, add-ons, etc.